# limit of O(1) as N tends to Infinity

Tags: uos

I have a quantity like Var(w_i) and it is O(1), where O is big-o.
I need limiting value of this variance. limit is on n, i.e. n--> Infinity
What will be limit ( n--> Infinity) of O(1). Is it Infinity?

Answer (score 0):

It's an unknown, but finite, constant, since O(1) by definition means something that is not related to `n`.